# Virtualbox is asking for permissions with genymotion & emulator is not starting?

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

When I am starting genymotion, it is asking for virtualbox permissions(UAC) over and over again. It is okay to do so (if it results in launching the emulator), but this forms a never ending 'permission asking' loop. In the published section it is clearly mentioning "Oracle corporation".

I am using virtual box 2.8.1 and virtualbox 5.1.18 with windows 7.

Thanks,

Comment: Change your bios setting, Enable VT-x from bios setting

Comment: This is not the solution. I have already done that.

Comment: try reinstalling genymotion and virtualbox

Comment: @Nilabja This is a good solution, what about, if this thing started happening again in the future?? Reinstall again??

Comment: I have never faced such issues with genymotion so I don't know about future, in future there might be new versions of genymotion or virtualbox will be available that may solve the issue @Saleh_Ninja

Answer (score 0):

The reason Genymotion triggers this at startup is that it asks VirtualBox for the list of installed devices. This results in several calls to VBoxManage, an executable provided by VirtualBox. Unfortunately, each time this executable is called you get an UAC.

Comment: Thanks, you are taking some sense. What would be the solution here?

Comment: The only "solution" I know of is to relax security settings, but that's not really acceptable :/

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to virtual box  File-> Host Network Manager

2.It will show available host only networks

3.Remove the ones which are not needed

Happy Coding:)